# cordova windows phone 8 how to add a plugin

Tags: c#, cordova

Hello im trying to use the InAppBrowser in my cordova project.

But i dont get it working.
I have downloaded the files InAppBrowser.cs and InAppBrowser.js and put the .cs file inside the project root folder and the .js file inside the www folder.

I also add to the root folder config.xml file the plugin tag.

```
<widget>
    <access origin="*"/>
    <feature name="InAppBrowser" value="InAppBrowser" />
</widget>
```

Unfortunately it doenst work.

Someone knows what im missing?

Answer (score 0):

Am i too late answering this ? Anyway.. i think you should make use of CLI.

First install node.js. 
http://nodejs.org/download/

Then git installer.
http://git-scm.com/downloads

Then Hit Windows+R and type cmd to open command prompt.

After that follow these steps to create a new project, then add your platform(ie WP8)
[http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/guide_cli_index.md.html](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/guide%5fcli%5findex.md.html)

Windows Phone 8 Plugin Resource.
http://plugreg.com/plugins#platform=wp8

Select any plugin
For eg, File plugin by apache.
just copy and paste the code to your command prompt.
Hit enter, the plugin will be installed automatically.

Then use it normally. or just read the plugin documentations.

:-)